# Lost Samsung Galaxy Ace 2

Tags: android, phone

I have lost my Samsung galaxy ace 2. There is a SIM card inside, i know my number and it still has some battery in it. Unfortunately i left the phone on silent and i don't have any phone tracking software installed.

I have searched my house for days but still have had no hope, please help!

Comment: https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager if your phone software is up to date try there first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "[Find My Mobile](http://findmymobile.samsung.com/login.do)". If you have connected your Samsung-phone with your samsung account, than you can find it.

You can also lock your phone with this tool.

Comment: the problem is though i have now realized it is out of battery. is there a GPS tracker or anything i can use? and the Samsung phone finder tells you all about "find my mobile" but there isn't actually a way of using it!

Comment: No if it's out of battery than you can't find it.